# SQL Server wrong results from query. Maybe index?

Tags: sql-server

I've got an interesting problem. I have the following very simple stored procedure that has been running correctly for the last three months:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetResults]
    @WorkID VARCHAR(15), 
    @Years VARCHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        [EmployeeID], [WorkID], [Years]
    FROM 
        [Table].[Schema].[Results]
    WHERE
        Years = @Years AND WorkID = @WorkID
    ORDER BY 
        Years DESC
END
```

Saturday, it started saying that there where no results when I had a web application hit this stored procedure.

However, when I go and run this procedure inside of SSMS, I get the correct results back. When I copy and paste this code into another tab (inside of SSMS) and run it, I get the right results back.

I have been working with the front end developer, so we have been commenting things out and we have determined that as long as we don't have the condition `WorkID = @WorkID`, we get results back. If we allow this condition, the results will almost always come back with 0 results. We have found that if we restart the server or run an alter procedure command, that it the web applications will sometimes return the correct results once, but if we re-query it will return as 0 results.

We assumed that the parameter `@WorkID` was being passed incorrectly, BUT looking at the logs it is obvious that it is correct; furthermore, I can go into the code and hardcode a WorkID that I know has results and it still returns 0 results.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    [EmployeeID], [WorkID], [Years]
FROM 
    [Table].[Schema].[Results]
WHERE
    Years = '1' AND WorkID = 'SomeKnownWorkID'
```

Once again, if we run this through SSMS everything works, as soon as we call this through a web application it brings back 0 results. I finally disabled a non-unique clustered index (below) and everything appeared to start working again.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-WorkID] 
    ON [schema].[Results] ([WorkID] ASC, [Years] ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,  
             SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I don't think this could have caused the issue. Any suggestions? I've never seen anything quite like this.

Comment: Running a query from SSMS and from an application *should* make no difference **if** the permissions are identical and both are run in the context of the same database. WAs the query perhaps running slowly before you were hitting the timeout value?

Comment: SSMS and .NET (or most other client libs, for that matter) do not by default use the same settings, meaning you probably hit [different execution plans](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html). Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on your point of view) disabling the index forced generation of new execution plans, meaning you may have wiped out whatever evidence you had of a (possible) optimizer bug. First things first, though: establish that the web app does not use the `READ UNCOMMITTED` transaction isolation level explicitly; all bets are off otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure that both where running against the same database ?

Comment: Indexes only influence the query plan. SQL Server is a very reliable product. Have you tried the exact values that were in the log. I would also suspect what Jeroen indicates- I really hope you are not using Read Uncommitted on an updateable system.

Comment: Guys, I've wrapped the procedure in the following:  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; 
 Begin Transaction --- And it still doesn't bring back correct resutls

Comment: @GuidoG we are running against the same DB

Comment: @Larnu.  The query is taking less then .5 seconds to run....This is really bizarre.

Comment: @Benjamin moskovtis -- I added a insert into statement at the beginning of the procedure to capture all the parameters coming in.  Everything looks fine.

Comment: If the stored proc has been running correctly for the last 3 months, then something in the app must have changed. Can you post the code where it's calling the sp? What's the datatype of `WorkID`?

Comment: It appears I had a procedure being called earlier that was causing the issue.  As soon as we put the Transaction Isolation Level Read Committed, everything cleared up.  This should be the default so why has it changed?  Any ideas?  Thanks.  @Jeroen Mostert please submit this as an answer so we can mark it as the answer for future references.  Thanks Guys!

Comment: Read committed is the default transaction isolation level. Most of the time (unless its a read only database) Read Uncommitted will cause all kinds of difficult to understand issues. When I said SQL Server is reliable I assumed you were at least in Read Committed. Any car is unsafe if you drive with the doors wide open with you sitting with your legs up on the dashboard.